# copy rows of pandas dataframe to a new dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv

i have a dataframe almost like this one :

```
id name numOfppl
1  A     30
2  B     31
3  C     10
4  D     0
.
.
.
31  comp  52
```

These numbers are coming from a python code.
Once we have 5 rows where numOfppl >=30, the code will stop and return all the rest of the rows to a new dataframe.

my code so far:

```
df[df['numOfppl'] >= 30].iloc[:5]
```

if more rows are added, how can i copy them to a new Dataframe ?

Comment: pandas is not a great choice to capture data that is being dynamically generated.  I'd suggest you generate all data in some kind of dictionary of lists, stop on whatever criteria you want, and *then* it is a snap to put it all into a df.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have created a dataframe for the condition you mentioned, you need all the other rows to be in a new dataframe, right? 
Please check with the below

```
df_1 = df[df['numOfppl'] >= 30].iloc[:5]
df_2 = df[~df.isin(df_1)].dropna()
```

Here df_1 will have 5 rows as you mentioned with the condition and rest all the rows will be copied to df_2. 
Also, for newly added rows (later) you can directly copy them into dataframe df_2

Comment: thank you for your answer. but what is a in "isin(a)" ?

Comment: Pandas isin allows you to check values in same or other dataframes. I have just edited the answer. It should be isin(df_1) instead isin(a). In dataframe df_1 you set some condition and insert rows. In dataframe df_2 you insert all the other rows that are not present in df_1.